# FontAwesome icon (::before) is too big of 0.5px

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have a biiiiig design issue. A 0.5px one to be exact. I use FontAwesome for my icons and I've noticed that the icons (which should be 14x14px when `font-size` is set to `14px`), are 14x14.5px. It means that if I had some `padding` around my icon it won't be perfectly centered, and I should then set a `padding` of `.5px` to compensate. The problem seem to come from FontAwesome's `::before` (the `<i>` tag is indeed 14x14px). Any idea on how to solve this?

With even padding, I get uneven dimensions:

[image]

With uneven padding, I get even dimensions:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any padding around the Icon. The dimension of the icon isn't a perfect square and so the width and height aren't the exact same. The center issue is just an optical effect.

Comment: Have you tried to overwrite the styling for the icon?

Comment: @iamrobin. please check the new image. The padding has to be uneven in order for the icon to be centered.

Comment: @SuperDJ gonna try that right now.

Comment: @SuperDJ Didn't fix it :/

Comment: Images of code will not do

Answer (score 0):

A have a similar issue when using http://fusetheme.com, it turns out the theme has a CSS styling for `i`. Instead of resetting `i`, I chose to use `span` which solves the problem for me.

Perhaps this will help other people with similar issue with their own themes.